# Variable doesn't pass to filter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a search algorithm and want to use $needle from query in Laravel collection filter method. But I'm sure that I'm passing a value and even checking for it but I get an error that needle is empty

Code:

```
if ( array_key_exists('search', $query) && $query['search'] != '' ) {

      $needle = strtolower($query['search']);

      $orders->filter(function ($order) use ($needle) {

           foreach ($order as $attribute => $value) {

               if ( strpos($needle, strtolower($value)) !== false ) {

                    return $order;

               }

           }

      });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've inverted `strpos` function parameters, it should be `haystack, needle`, so try inverting values inside